# Strategy for managing tagging? - Folksonomy or controlled vocabulary?

Tags: discussion, tags

I've noticed that as SO has got bigger, some guidelines have introduced for tagging, taking it from a completely uncontrolled 'folksonomy' and moving it towards a controlled vocabulary.

Is there a plan for managing the tags as they grow?

Failing that, what strategies should be considered?

In a bid for an informed discussion, I've attached a good (free) book on controlled vocabularies. Other resources on tagging for very large collections like SO, would be appreciated and upvoted!

---

to NKOS-L
Just to let you know that Patricia Harpring,s book, "Introduction to Controlled Vocabularies, Terminology for Art, Architecture, and Other Cultural Works" is now available on the Web at http://www.getty.edu/research/conducting_research/standards/intro_controlled_vocab/.

Each chapter is available as HTML and also as a printer-friendly PDF.

Comment: The "plan" may well be to thrash out issues on meta as they come up...

Comment: @dmckee +1 for the pun

Comment: Wait, what pun? "Thrash" vs. "thresh"?

Comment: @Popular: I, too, don't see a pun. I was prepared to quietly take credit, but it's bothering me.

Comment: @dmckee, what @mmyers said.